DynamoDb Kinesis Data Stream ordering guarantee
I am investigating DynamoDb streams vs DynamoDb Kinesis Data Streams.
The Kinesis Data Streams documentation read:

The Kinesis data stream records might appear in a different order than when the item changes occurred. The same item notifications might also appear more than once in the stream. You can check the ApproximateCreationDateTime attribute to identify the order that the item modifications occurred in, and to identify duplicate records.

I am wondering if it guarantee at least these two

Does it guarantee that events related to the same item are ordered?
In case of duplicates, does it guarantee that eventually all the events for a given items will be emitted in order? eg: E1, E3, E2, E3, ... and not E1, E3, E2, ...

Currently I am copy events from DynamoDb stream to kinesis, and my solution does not offer a better guarantee than the above.

For DynamoDB integration with KDS the items are put on the stream using PutRecords API which kinesis does not provide any order guarantee for:

Kinesis Data Streams attempts to process all records in each PutRecords request. A single record failure does not stop the processing of subsequent records. As a result, PutRecords doesn't guarantee the ordering of records. If you need to read records in the same order they are written to the stream, use PutRecord instead of PutRecords, and write to the same shard.

So while the same item will enter the same shard, it's order is not guaranteed.
In contrast, DynamoDB Streams guarantees order for item level changes.

No, Kinesis Data Streams does not guarantee strict ordering or eventual consistency for events related to the same item. While you can use ApproximateCreationDateTime to attempt to order events, it's not reliable. Your solution should be designed to handle out-of-order and duplicate events.
